# Optim() function in R

Tags: r, function, optimization, parameters, log-likelihood

I am trying to optimize the parameters of a function with a bound using R's optim() function. Here is the function: [Function, because mathjax does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDKdD.png)
The code snippet below is my implementation of its Log-Likelihood function, which is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtqQV.png)

```
likelihood_levy <- function(params, x){
  mu <- params[1]
  sigma <- params[2]
  n <- length(x)

  ans <- ((1.5 * n) * log(sigma)) +
      sum(log(1 / (x - mu))) -
      (n * log(sqrt(2*pi) * sigma)) - 
      (0.5 * sigma * sum(1 / (x - mu)))
  }

  return(ans)
}

optim(c(-10, 2), likelihood_levy, x = sample1, method="L-BFGS-B",
      lower = c(min(sample1) - 0.001, 0))
```

How do I add parameter bounds to the function definition? For example, the first parameter must be lower than x and the second shouldn't be lower than 0.

Note: If I use the "L-BFGS-B" method of optim() function, I get an error that says "L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'"
Any solutions to this problem would be great too!

Thanks!

Comment: Optim only accepts absolute bounds, not relative ones, such as x must be smaller than y, in that case you need a different solver.

Comment: Anyway, the error seems to be that your function evaluates to infinity or a missing value somewhere and that breaks the optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

1. There is an extraneous right brace bracket just before the return statement.
2. Even if lower ensures that x - mu is positive we can still have problems when the numeric gradient is calculated so use a derivative free method (which we do below) or provide a gradient function to optim.
3. optim calculates the minimum but we want the maximum likelihood, not the minimum likelihood.  Tell optim to maximize (which we do below) or use the negative log likelihood instead of the log likelihood.
4. The starting value should be feasible, i.e. it should be such that the log likelihood can be calculated at it and produce a finite value while satisfying the constraint that mu < min(x).
5. We need to handle the situation where mu < min(x) does not hold.
6. sample1 is missing so we can't reproduce the problem in the question.

Fixing all these we have

```
likelihood_levy <- function(params, x){
  mu <- params[1]
  sigma <- params[2]
  n <- length(x)
  ans <- if (mu >= min(x)) -Inf
    else ((1.5 * n) * log(sigma)) +
      sum(log(1 / (x - mu))) -
      (n * log(sqrt(2*pi) * sigma)) - 
      (0.5 * sigma * sum(1 / (x - mu)))
  return(ans)
}

set.seed(123)
sample1 <- rnorm(25)
st <- c(min(sample1) - 0.001, 1)
res <- optim(st, likelihood_levy, x = sample1, control = list(fnscale = -1))

str(res)
```

giving

```
List of 5
 $ par        : num [1:2] -2.25 1.61
 $ value      : num -46.6
 $ counts     : Named int [1:2] 45 NA
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "function" "gradient"
 $ convergence: int 0
 $ message    : NULL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works perfectly!
I had another question, if you do not mind, but in the function where it goes
ans <- if (mu > min(x)) -Inf
Why -inf? I had tried this earlier, except with 0

Comment: Oh oops nevermind.
I realized that log(0) would be undefined, hence you used -inf.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the function `likelihood_levy` is either returning a value greater than `.Machine$double.xmax` or within the function, a division by zero is occurring. This line may be the culprit:

```
sum(log(1 / (x - mu)))
```

if `x` is equal to, or just very close to `mu`, the problem would occur. You could add some defensive code to check for this. However:

> the first parameter must be lower than x

I don't think there is a way to do that with `optim`